# Pandas: How to exclude the matched one and get only the highlighted differences in dataframe with Multilevel Column Index

Tags: python, pandas

I will be showing the difference of two dataframes using below,

```
df_all = pd.concat([df_source.set_index('id'), df_target.set_index('id')], 
                   axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second']).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df_source.columns[1:]]
def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    
    other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

df_final.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
```

[image]

now how do i show only the rows which is having mismatch? in  this case Id 103 and 106 rows and exclude other rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter and split the columns into 2 subsets of columns with `First` and `Second`, use [`.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to keep only one level of column index to make the 2 portion with same column index to facilitate comparison. Finally, use [`.compare()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) to compare and highlight the differences of the 2 portions, as follows:

```
df1 = df_final.filter(like='First').droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
df2 = df_final.filter(like='Second').droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
df1.compare(df2).rename({'self': 'First', 'other': 'Second'}, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
           lastname              profession        
              First Second            First  Second
id                                                 
103  Brenn_modified  Brenn              NaN     NaN
106             NaN    NaN  doctor_modified  doctor
```